# How to set git for this specific scenario?

Tags: git

First of all, sorry for the bad title, idk how the scenario below is called.

I'm developing what will be a nugget package. Since this will be a publicly available source code, I intend to create a repo named `Main` for it.

But for ease of development and testing, it would be nice to have a test client pointing directly to it, so I can change whatever in the actual pkg code and have it reflected instantaneously on the test client, instead of publishing a new version of the pkg and updating on the client.

However, I do not wish to expose this test client on the `Main` repo, for the sake of a clean project. So I figured I would create a repo `Dev`, that would be `Main`+TestClient.

How can I set this? A repo that is contained by another repo? or perhaps the other way around: a repo that contains others repos?

Comment: Sounds like you’re talking about a git sub-module.

Comment: tests are an essential part of a "clean project" :)

Comment: yeah, but im not talking about unit tests or automated tests, im talking about a client which I can test the actual "usability" of the api... to test how "good" my api feels and how well it fits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After evolutionbox comment, I dug around and found this [doc here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and just by `git submodule add MasterRepoHere` I got what I wanted!

Comment: I’m glad I could be helpful.